# Is there an organization who repackages old LEGO bricks into sets to give to underprivileged children?

Tags: sets

Does Lego have a program by which we can return old LEGO parts so they can be reassembled into packages for underprivileged kids? My kids, and now grandkids, have always played with LEGO bricks and I have a large collection of parts, not in their original boxes and would like to give them to an organization who would reassemble them into workable sets for disadvantaged kids. I hate to just throw them away as I must have several hundred dollars worth of parts.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to locate a nearby [BrickLink vendor](http://bricklink.com) and request them to sell the pieces and donate the proceeds to charity. So far as I know, this is the best way to donate, as the pieces are sold for their appropriate value and the money can be donated as you wished. You may consider donating the pieces to Creations for Charity as well.

If you really want to donate parts, the best way would be to use the money from other suggestions to purchase general purpose block sets, and donate those.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any such global organization, but if you're willing to part with LEGO toys, you may want to consider helping an organization in your neighbourhood. Hospitals will most certainly welcome any donation for their children's ward, and I suppose schools may have a use for it as well. I don't think they would care that much if sets are incomplete, as long as the parts themselves are still in good playable shape.

That's the [path which has been chosen](http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=6813) for the [Brickset charity raffle](http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=6464), for example.

Answer (score 5):

Recreating a LEGO set from mixed up pieces is extremely time consuming. Even if you are just missing a few pieces, since LEGO makes tens of thousands of shapes and sizes. Even simply verifying that a "set of 352 pieces" has exactly the correct "352 pieces" is very time consuming. The good news is kids and adults LOVE using mixed up pieces to create their "MOCs" (MOC means My Own Creation).

www.BrickRecycler.com is a great place to send LEGO pieces, and know they will end up being used, and loved. They even offer to pay for postage if you are sending from anywhere in the US. They work with nonprofit organizations too, and have shipped hundreds of thousands of pieces. There is more information on the web site, including a link a really encouraging video of kids in Haiti having a blast with bulk LEGO pieces.

Comment: You seem to have something odd going on in the mark-up of your website resulting in a rather massive table of white text on a white background, which is considered a little suspicious by some, as if you're hiding something?

Answer (score 1):

sorry I am a little late to the game...I am founder of a new charity in Kansas, USA that accepts donated LEGOs and sorts them into sets based on original LEGO sets. We gift these sets to underprivileged kids through foster care associations.

If you are still looking for a place to donate your sets - I will take them. Unsorted, any condition, with instructions or not. Feel free to contact me for more information.

Matthew Gould
(as yet unnamed Lego charity)
USA-9 one 3 - two 0 six - six three 0 0
@mdgouldkc

Comment: Hi Matthew, and welcome to LEGO Answers. It would be good if you could add the contact details you've included here on your [Public Profile](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/3730/matthew-gould). In general (a bit like Wikipedia) self promotion isn't encouraged ;)